# Reversing a wpf Visual State transition

Tags: wpf, storyboard, visualstatemanager

I have a custom WPF control with two visual states - Enabled & Disabled. The disabled state has a simple transition animation that disables the control, then fades it out after a short delay. Then I have the reverse of the animation, where it fades in the control, and re-enables it (with no delay), when transitioning to the Enabled state.

The problem I have is if I change the state from Disabled and then back to enabled again before it had started to fade out, then I still have to wait through the fade-in animation before it re-enables the control, where in actuality, it could just enable the control straight away, and avoid the fade-in part.

What's the right way to go about fixing this? I sort of need to set the start point of the "Enabled" transition storyboard based on the current time in the Disabled transition storyboard (minus the initial delay).

Another way, I guess, is to have two states one saying Disabled and one saying faded. Once the disabled state animation completes, if it was possible to change visual states from a storyboard, I could enter the Faded state after the disabled storyboard had completed. Then I can have different transitions defined from Disabled to Enabled and Faded to Enabled.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for the enabling and disabling Animations, do i guess correctly that you have both the From and To values defined?  that would account for the behavior that you describe.

if you leave out the From value, specifying only the To value, the specified property will animate from whatever its value is at the time (so, for instance, half faded) to whatever you specify.  this is instead of popping the value to the From value you specify and then animating to the To value.

Comment: My storyboard has a number of steps in it to go from the disabled to enabled state. But, to your point, in a simple animation, e.g. just changing opacity, you can get _close_ to the behavior we want by not setting the From property.  But there is still a drawback - the animation takes just as long as it would have, regardless of whether it starts from 0 or 50% opacity. This means the fade back appears to be slower, and the delay becomes annoying.

Comment: I'm trying to get the fade back to take half the time, if the fade in was only allowed to execute for half of it's normal duration.
Yes, in case you are wondering, I am a perfectionist.

Comment: sounds like you would need to set the SpeedRatio property based on how far the animation needs to go.

Comment: So... how would I find "how far the animation needs to go"? I'd need to be able to get the current time of the state changing animation, and then set the correct start time in the reverse state change animation. Is this possible?

Comment: well, i was thinking more along the lines of comparing the current value of whatever property you're animating to the To value.  the ratio of the full difference to that difference is the SpeedRatio.

really, what you want is for the speed of the property change to be the same.  that could be accomplished by changing either the duration or the speed ratio so that (SpeedRatio) * (To value - current value) / (Duration) is the same in all cases.

Comment: Ok, so how do you do either of these things in a XAML control template - remembering that this is a look-less custom control, where the animation behavior is defined in the XAML...

Comment: i think you'd have to do this in a little codebehind for your custom control (i know, i know -- i hate to say that).  whenever you trigger enabling or disabling, set the SpeedRatio appropriately.  want to post a simplified example of the code for your custom control?